# What is the issue with this program

Tags: java, abstract-class

```
interface A{
    void setColor(int color);
}
abstract class B implements A{
    abstract int setColor(int color);
}

class Test extends B{
    public static void main(Strings args){
        int setColor(int color){ }
    }
}
```

this is showing the compile time error of

```
';' expected 
int setColor(int color){
}
```

above program is wrong my actual program is

```
interface A{
    void setColor(int color);
}
abstract class B implements A{
    abstract int setColor(int color);
}

class Test extends B{
    int setColor(int color){ }
    public static void main(Strings args){

    }
}
```

in this program i am having the compilation error which i have mentioned in the comment section

Comment: interface A{
 void setColor(int color);
}
abstract class B implements A{
 abstract int setColor(int color);
}

class Test extends B{
 int setColor(int color){ }
 public static void main(Strings args){
  
 }
}

Comment: here is the compilation error of the above program setColor(int) in B cannot implement setColor(int) in A and Test is not abstract and does not override abstract method setColor in A.

Comment: i know that a subclass of a abstract method with implements the methods  of the abstract class need not be abstract the why it is showing compilation error like Test is not abstract. i have mentioned in the comment section above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to declare a method inside `main`.  Put the definition of `setColor` **outside** `main`!

Comment: i agree with you but it was my fault to post the wrong program the actual program in below the privious program and in the comment section i have mentioned the compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a method (`setColor`) in another (`main()`).
You have to rewrite your `Test` class, like:

```
 class Test extends B{

     int setColor(int color){ }
     public static void main(Strings args){
     }
 }
```